# Using cramer's rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm asked to solve the systems using cramers  rule

$3x    +3z =27$

$6x+2y+5z=57$

$-2x-4y=-24$

When I solve the Determinant I get a $0$ which leads me to say that the system is undefined where I have no solution, but my answer is given as $(8,2,1)$. If I plug in those numbers they work in the system but I don't understand that if they work why is it that I get a $0$ as my determinant?

Comment: Determinant 0 implies you could have infinite solutions. For example (6,3,3) is also a solution

Comment: Yea I just read that when you get a 0 in the determinant it could mean it is inconsistent or infinitely many solutions and that if that happens then this system can not be solved using Cramer's. I used Gauss-Jordan and saw it was infinitely many solutions.